# connecting light

Tags: switches, relay, load

I quickly drew up the lights I wanted to install and connect to two relay and be controlled with one switch. I want the lights on both relays to turn on with the switch. Would the way i drew it work correctly? 
[image]

Comment: it is not possible to answer your question because we have no information about the relays

Comment: the relays are connected as shown (87a) is not used

Comment: also your question is unclear because you have made no mention of the application  .... it appears to be used in a vehicle of some type .... but it should be stated in words

Comment: what is `87a` ?

Comment: this question is unclear and should be closed .... the OP is assuming that we are mind readers

Comment: Okay, i wanted to know if it should work correctly before installing it in the car.

Comment: Hood lights is a given.

Comment: There is no mention of "hood lights" (whatever they are) in the question. The numbers on the relays are peculiar to automotive relays.

Answer (score 1):

Those automotive/European terminal numbers on the relays are meaningless to many of us.  Much better to use proper schematic symbols for the relays and switch, as below.

If terminals 85 and 86 are the relay coil, it appears you are not applying power to the coils - you have one side grounded, and the other side grounded through the switch, so it won't work - no power to the coil.  The circuit below will work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCi6QJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, if you want the single switch to control all the lights, why have two relays?

Comment: i figured the load is too much for one relay. So my way wont work?, i have the relay receiving power at 87.  w

Comment: The coil terminals are 85 and 86.  30 is the moving contact (common), and 87 is the Normally Open contact (no connection to the coil).  87A is the Normally Closed contact.  If you used proper symbols, as above, rather than boxes with cryptic numbers, this should have been readily apparent.

Comment: DIN 72552:  85  Coil;
 86  Coil; 
 87  Normally Open (NO);
 87a  Normally Closed (NC) - not present on 4 pin relays; & 
 30  Common connection to NO & NC terminals;